# Titan graph database: speed up AND and OR gremlin queries using the Indexing backends

Tags: solr, cassandra, titan, gremlin

I have used Titan 1.0 in production. (Cassandra + Solr) I was wondering how can I speed up AND/ OR queries through indexing backend. Suppose mixed index has been defined on "user_info" and "vertex_label" fields. How can I tell Titan to use indexing backend as a source of data preparation for the following query or other similar ones:

```
g.V().or(__.has("user_info",Text.textRegex("job=Teacher")),
      __.has("vertext_label","user")))
```

I have checked this query using query.force-index=true to see whether it uses any kind of index or not; but the thrown exception showed it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

It was [answered](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/C-_Krug0B3w/K_uo78-HHAAJ) on the Aurelius mailing list, but since SO prefers text rather than links, here it is again:

Split it into 2 queries and merge the result:

```
result = g.V().has("user_info", Text.textRegex("job=Teacher")).toSet()
result.addAll(g.V().has("vertex_label", "user"))
```

Or make use of mid-traversal index lookups (requires TP 3.2):

```
g.V().has("user_info", Text.textRegex("job=Teacher")).aggregate("x").cap("x").
  V().has("vertex_label", "user").aggregate("x").cap("x")
```